# How to open a window by clicking on a specific point on a chart?

Tags: python, qt, window, new-window

I have the task to build up an interactive plot which i have already done more or less. But now I am supposed to give specific information about a point in a graph for example P(8|6) and by clicking on this point there should open a new window with specific information. Adding the information to the window wont be the problem but the window itself. How I can open a window by clicking on this specific point (keep in mind, it is no button since it changes from graph to graph)?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet since i have no clue how to add this feature into my plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is qwt!  Study the documentation and examples for that project like your life depended on it, and you will find exactly what you need.

I wrote up a pretty complete example a year or so ago; but it is in C++; converting it to python should be pretty straight forward.

https://github.com/peteristhegreat/qwt_generic

Hope that helps.